# How to import a library from Export-SPWeb outputs?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, restore, export, import

I am trying to understand how to restore an arbitrary library to an arbitrary site in an arbitary site collection - inspired by some future user announcing he accidentally deleted a document from the library (and recycle bin is not an option). Let's assume the user does not even know the document name but would recognize it if a copy of the lib were restored from a backup.

With that goal, I've been experimenting with some Powershell scripts which export sites in my farm. This one uses file compression by default:

```
Get-SPSite | foreach-object {
$_.allwebs | foreach-object {
    $ExportDir = "\\BLACKTIP\SharePointBackups\Export-WebSites\" + $_.Url.replace("http://","").Replace("/","-");
    $ExportFname = $ExportDir + ".cmp";
    Export-SPWeb -Identity $_.Url -Path $ExportFname -Force
}
```

}

Consider a given subsite HR within a site collection `http://blacktip/sites/cbmi`:
I see the following files in the export directory:

[image: files-exported]

I looked over the syntax for Import-SPWeb and tried a couple of things:

```
import-spweb `http://blacktip/sites/cbmi/restoreHR` -Path "C:\SharepointBackups\Export-WebSites\blacktip-sites-cbmi-HR.cmp"
```

The above is based on the hope that maybe it would create a subsite called restoreHR based on the properties of the exported site. Got error: **Cannot find an SPWeb object with Id or Url : `http://blacktip/sites/cbmi/restoreHR`** which of course makes sense.

So, I created a subsite called HRrestored (not knowing what template to use) and then I got this error: **Cannot import site. The exported site is based on the template STS#1 but the destination site is based on the template STS#0. You can import sites only into
 sites that are based on same template as the exported site.**

What are the best practices for something like this? How to the "pros" handle these sort of ad-hoc requests for restoration of arbitrary resources within Sharepoint (assuming granular backups have been taken, what are best practices for restoring things?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that source and destination sites are not created from the same template. The source site is based upon Blank Site template (STS#1) but the destination site is based upon Team site template (STS#0). So, create a site with Blank site template and perform the import again.

Here is the list of site templates: http://blogs.technet.com/b/araviraj/archive/2008/06/18/sharepoint-templates-types.aspx

More about backing up Sites or list: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx